# Algorithm to find how many times a string A needs to be stated such that it contains string B as substring

Tags: algorithm

I haven't been able to come up with a bullet proof answer to this question. My solution fails few cases. I would appreciate some insights.

### Question:

Given two strings A and B, return the number of times A needs to be stated such that it contains string B?

Example #1:

- String A : abcd
- String B : cdabcdab

Should return 3 because:

- abcdabcdabcd  ( A repeated 3 times)
- cdabcdab ( B is contained in now)

Example #2:

- String A = abcd
- String B = d

should return 1 because B is already a substring of A.

Example #3:

- String A = abcd
- String B = cda

Should return 2 because:

- abcdabcd
- cda

Example #4:

- String A = abcd
- String B = cdb

Should return -1, it doesn't matter how many times we state A, there is no way we can produce B.

Few insights I have noticed:

1. Order of characters matter
2. A must contain at least all the
   characters in B
3. Neither A or B needs to be a substring of the
   other.
4. There must be an overlap between the end of one string and
   the beginning of the other.

Comment: What's your solution?

Answer (score 2):

If |B| > 2|A| - 2 and B occurs in A^n, then A occurs in B. Count and remove all complete instances of A in B, and then the solution is this count plus the solution to the same problem with A's removed from B.

Otherwise, it is guaranteed that if B appears in A^n, it appears in A^3. Construct A^3 and find the first occurrence of B in it. Find and remove any complete instances of A appearing after the end of B's appearance in A^3. Return 3 minus the number of removed instances.

Examples:

```
f(abcd, cdabcdab)
|cdabcdab| > 2|abcd| - 2 since 8 > 2*4 - 2
   ^^^^
   first instance of A in B; no more, so return 1 + f(cdab, abcd) = 3
f(cdab, abcd)
|cdab| < 2|abcd| - 2 since 4 < 2*4 - 2
abcdabcdabcd
  ^^^^
  first instance of B in A; one instance of A after B, so return 3 - 1 = 2.

f(d, abcd)
|d| < 2|abcd| - 2, since 1 < 2*4 - 2
abcdabcdabcd
   ^
   first instance of B in A; two instances of A after B, so return 3 - 2 = 1.

f(cda, abcd)
|cda| = 2|abcd| - 2 since 3 = 2*4 - 2
abcdabcdabcd
  ^^^
  first instance of B in A; one instance of A after B, so return 3 - 1 = 2.

f(cdb, abcd)
|cbd| = 2|abcd| - 2 since 3 = 2*3 - 2
abcdabcdabcd
            ^ no instances of B in A; return -1.
```

Some minor optimizations include:

- if |B| = 0, return 0.
- if |B| = 1, use A^1 instead of A^3.
- if |B| < |A| + 2, use A^2 instead of A^3.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it as like the code segment below. I noticed that no matter how many times we *duplicate* string A, this number (of times) can't be greater than length of string B. I hope this helps. Please note my answer runs in O(N^2) time. Not Ideal but any brute force solution should give you a good start towards the optimum/final solution.

```
string A = "abcd";
string B = "cda";
int i = 1;
string S = A;
while (i < B.Length)
{
     S = S + A;
     i++;
     if(S.Contains(B))
          break;
}
if(i==B.Length-1 && !S.Contains(B))
     Console.WriteLine(-1); //not found
Console.WriteLine(i); //the solution
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a,b,s="";
    cin>>a>>b;int count=0;
    size_t f = a.find(b);
    if(f==string::npos)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<b.length() && s.find(b)==string::npos;++i)
        {
            s.append(a);
            count++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<1<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if(s.find(b)!=string::npos)
        cout<<count;
    else
        cout<<0<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If A is longer than B then return 1 if B is in A.

if A is same length as B and they are equal return 1.

Look for the location in which B contains A, with a wrap around. 
  So A is abc and B is bca you will find that A is in B starting at [2].  Then start covering B with A starting with that location and count how many times you had to repeat A.  Note that if covering fails, you need to keep searching for other possible places where A is in B.

Answer (score 0):

it is guaranteed that if B appears in A^n, it appears in A^3.
So writing simple Java Code :

```
import java.io.*;
public class StringDemo {
   public static void print(String x){
      System.out.println(x);  
   }
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      String A = "abcd";
      int alen = A.length();
      String B = "cda";
      int blen = B.length();
      String C = A+A+A;
      int op = -1;
      if (C.indexOf(B) > -1 ){
          op = 3;
          C = C.substring(0,alen*2);
          if (C.indexOf(B) > -1){
              op =  2;
              C = C.substring(0,alen);
              if (C.indexOf(B) > -1){
                  op = 1;
              }
          }

      }
      print(Integer.toString(op));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question I solved few days ago. 
The Question  :
 Given two strings A and B, find the minimum number of times A has to be repeated such that B is a substring of it. If no such solution, return -1.
For example, with A = "abcd" and B = "abcdabcd".
Return 3, because by repeating A three times (“abcdabcdabcd”), B is a substring of it; and B is not a substring of A repeated two times ("abcdabcd").
One probable solution from my side can be this:

```
public class test1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a  = " abcd";
    String b = "abcdabcd";

    System.out.println(fix(a,b));
}
public static int fix(String a,String b) {
    StringBuffer sbr  = new StringBuffer(a);
    int c = 1 ;
    //for( ; sbr.length() < b.length() ; c++ ) {sbr.append(a) ; }
    while(sbr.length() < b.length() ) {
        sbr.append(a);
        c++ ;
    }

     String t = sbr.toString();
     // if str1 not contains then we can concatenate and we must increase the count
    if(!t.contains(b)) {
         t += a ;
         c++ ;
    }
    if(t.contains(b)) {
        c++ ;
    }
    return c ;

}
}
```

The output  will be 3 .abcdabcdabcd => 3 times abcd then abcdabcd will be a substring of it. That's why answer 3 is correct. If str1 has str2 the we increment the count by 1.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is naive, but I think it works fine. If anyone found a flaw in this, please let me know.

```
private static int countRepeatOfString(StringBuffer concatenate, String a, String b) {

    if (concatenate.length() == 0 || b.length() == 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    int maxConcatenateCount;

    /*  For cases like:
        String A - abcd  (length=4)       Longest possible would be:
        String B - cdabcdab (length=8)    abcdabcdabcd

        Let r = the ratio of String B length to String A length
            r + 2 is for taking care of case:
            String A - abc
            String B - c(abc)a
    */
    if (a.length() <= b.length()) {
        maxConcatenateCount = b.length() / a.length() + 2;
        return countOccurrence(maxConcatenateCount, concatenate, a, b);
    } else {
        return countOccurrence(2, concatenate, a, b);
    }
}

private static int countOccurrence(int maxConcatenateCount, StringBuffer concatenate, String a, String b) {
    boolean found = false;
    int currentConcatenateCount = 1;
    int repeatCount = 1;
    while (currentConcatenateCount <= maxConcatenateCount) {
        int index = concatenate.indexOf(b, 0);
        if (index != -1) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        concatenate.append(a);
        currentConcatenateCount++;
        repeatCount++;
    }

    if (found) {
        return repeatCount;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking the solution from @Patrick87

Here is the code:

```java
public class ATimesToContainB {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println();
        String a = "abcd";
        String b = "cdabcdabcdabcdab";
        System.out.println("Brute Force Multiply A :" + a + " n= " + atimesbBruteForce(a, b) + " to contain B " + b);
        System.out.println("Optimized Multiply A :" + a + " n= " + atimesb(a, b) + " to contain B " + b);


        System.out.println();
        a = "abcd";
        b = "cdabcdabcdabcdabab";
        System.out.println("Brute Force Multiply A :" + a + " n= " + atimesbBruteForce(a, b) + " to contain B " + b);
        System.out.println("Optimized Multiply A :" + a + " n= " + atimesb(a, b) + " to contain B " + b);


        System.out.println();
        a = "abcd";
        b = "cdabcdab";
        System.out.println("Brute Force Multiply A :" + a + " n= " + atimesbBruteForce(a, b) + " to contain B " + b);
        System.out.println("Optimized Multiply A :" + a + " n= " + atimesb(a, b) + " to contain B " + b);

        System.out.println();
        a = "abcd";
        b = "d";
        System.out.println("Brute Force Multiply A :" + a + " n= " + atimesbBruteForce(a, b) + " to contain B " + b);
        System.out.println("Optimized Multiply A :" + a + " n= " + atimesb(a, b) + " to contain B " + b);

        System.out.println();
        a = "abcd";
        b = "cda";
        System.out.println("Brute Force Multiply A :" + a + " n= " + atimesbBruteForce(a, b) + " to contain B " + b);
        System.out.println("Optimized Multiply A :" + a + " n= " + atimesb(a, b) + " to contain B " + b);

        System.out.println();
        a = "abcd";
        b = "cdb";
        System.out.println("Brute Force Multiply A :" + a + " n= " + atimesbBruteForce(a, b) + " to contain B " + b);
        System.out.println("Optimized Multiply A :" + a + " n= " + atimesb(a, b) + " to contain B " + b);


    }


    //O(n*m^2)
    private static int atimesbBruteForce(String a, String b) {

        int n = a.length();
        int m = b.length();
        String tempA = a;

        if (tempA.contains(b))
            return 1;

        for (int i = 1; i < m; i++) { // O(m)

            tempA = tempA + a;
            if (tempA.contains(b)) //O(n*m); since temp A length could be max "m" times a length which is "n", for checking contains it take O(textLength); O(m*n)
                return i + 1;
        }
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    }

    //Idea take from above stack overflow

    //O((m^2)/n)  -> i hope its right


    private static int atimesb(String a, String b) {
            int n = a.length();
            int m = b.length();


        if (m == 0)
            return 0;

        if (m == 1)
            return (a.contains(b) ? 1 : -1);

        int count;
        if (m > 2 * n - 2) {
            count = countTimes(b, a);  // O(m/n)

            if (count > 0) {
                return count + atimesb(a, removeByTimes(b, a)); // O(m)
            } else
                return count;
        } else if (m < n + 2) {
            a = a + a;
            count = countTimes(a, b); // O(m)

            if (count > 0) {
                return 1 + count;
            } else
                return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        } else {
            a = a + a + a;
            count = countTimes(a, b); // O(m)
            if (count > 0)
                return 3 - count;
            else return Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        }


    }


    private static String removeByTimes(String b, String a) {
        return b.replaceAll(a, "");
    }

    /**
     * It will count how many times "toCount" is occur in "fromCount" if occures at all
     *
     * @param fromToCount
     * @param toCount
     * @return How many times, otherwise 0 if not occur
     */
    private static int countTimes(String fromToCount, String toCount) {
        int count = 0;
        while (fromToCount.contains(toCount)) {
            fromToCount = fromToCount.replaceFirst(toCount, "");
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in Python2 for the same. I followed mathematical way of solving the expression

```
def google(a,b):
    x=(len(b)/len(a))+1
    print x
google("abcd","cda")
```